# Does "to show" function as an adverb modifying an adjective in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases, functions, infinitive-phrases

Does the usage of the infinitive ***to show*** serve the purpose the task below?

Task:  **write a sentence using the infinitive "to show" as an adverb modifying an adjective.**

I tried to use "to show" as an adverb in order to modify the adjective "beautiful" and "wonderful" in the sentences below:

1. Adam likes his job **to show** beautiful dresses
2. My mother likes cooking **to show** a wonderful hobby.

Comment: I'm sorry, but neither of your examples makes much sense.  Did you make them up?

Comment: Yes. I wrote them .

Comment: As I said, your examples make little sense. Perhaps you could try again?

Comment: Maria, it would help us understand if you told us what you *wanted* to say with these sentences, because the meaning of them is unclear.  If we knew what they were supposed to mean, then we could suggest a better use of *to show*.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how an infinitive can be an adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used google to find out about "infinitive phrase 'modifying an adjective'" and after a little research I found [this example](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/whats-an-infinitive-or-infinitive-phrase/):

> The movie was too quiet to hear.

The infinitive "to hear" modifies the adjective quiet.(* but see below)  Note that while it modifies the adjective (it tells how quiet it was), you couldn't just replace it with an adverb, as adverbs tend to come before adjectives that they modify.

This makes the task rather confusing! You can't "use an infinitive as an adverb" because the syntax for adverbs and infinitive phrases is different.

However, with this example, you should be able to think of a sentence that has the same structure, but uses "to show" instead of "to hear".

(*) BillJ observes that "to hear" is only allowed in this phrase because it is part of the phrase "too quiet to hear".  The sentence "The movie was quiet to hear" would be ungrammatical. Many adjectives don't allow for infinitive complements.  One adjective that *does* allow for an infinitive complement is "quick":

> She was quick to criticise.

I think it will be easier for you to make a natural sentence using "too ... to show ..." (and I expect your teacher will mark as correct) you should be aware of this subtle grammatical issue:  The infinitive is *licenced* by "too" and not by the adjective.

Comment: Actually, it would be a complement, not a modifier. The problem is that "quiet" is one of a large number of adjectives that don't license complements of any kind, so this rules out "to hear" as being licensed by “quiet”. This means that although “too quiet to hear” is a constituent (an adjective phrase), the infinitival "to hear" is in fact licensed by the “too” that modifies “quiet”. Incidentally, “to hear” is called a ‘hollow’ clause – hollow because the complement of “hear” is missing, though it’s understood as being “the movie”.

Comment: what about a slightly simpler "she was quick to eat"?

Comment: "Quick" does license complements, so "to eat" does qualify as its complement. Similarly in the more likely "She was quick to criticise".

Comment: I've edited, to note this.  I think at the Learner's level, it will be easier to form a natural sentence in a "too ... to show", and that is more important than trying to find adjective that licence complements, and for which "to show" forms a sentence whose meaning isn't too forced.